# How to write a chapter before table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

Suppose I am writing a report (report class used) and I want some chapters before the TOC what should I do? How to number the chapters from after the TOC?

Comment: just use `\chapter{}` before `\tableofcontents`, what did you try?

Comment: Are the pre-chapters numbered?  Do they appear in the TOC?  Does the numbering get reset as of the TOC?

Comment: I tried front matter back matter

Comment: They do appear in TOC

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It worked!!. Had not tried that. Nice and Easy

Comment: How to start the numbering of the chapters from chapters after TOC

Comment: use `\chapter*` for unnumerered ones (or switch to book class and use \frontmatter \chapter ... \tableofcontents \manmatter \chapter... (that being the main difference between report and book)

Comment: "\chapter*" will skip the TOC I want it to be in the TOC and unnumbered

Comment: not that you mentioned that in the question.... you can use `\addtocontents` to add the entries or as I say, use `\frontmatter` in book class, which makes unnumbered chapters in the toc by default

Comment: I don't want to use book class as it brings unnecessary headings on the top of each page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{intro}
something

\chapter{acknowledgements}
somebody

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{start here}
the real stuff

\chapter{more stuff}
\ldots

\end{document}
```